# aiomysql row locking when using multiple asyncio programs

Tags: python, mysql, python-asyncio, aio-mysql

I have a mysql table on aws mysql and as such my python asyncio program which is using aiomysql - https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql connects to a remote mysql database.

My table shop has the following fields: `id, names, product_id, payment_status`

The payment_status holds the status of an order i.e `paid,pending,cancelled`

lets say i start my asynio program on server `X` and the program starts going through my table shop updating the payment_status of various products.

In another machine, i have started another asynchio program exactly like the last one at machine `X` in machine `Y`, if the program at `X` starts working on the rows, does aiomysql lock such a row when asyncio has yielded control for a while so as to avoid the two programs working on the same row at the same time?.

Comment: did you look at record locking?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-record-locks